# Updating multiple field with javascript

Tags: javascript, hidden-field

I have next form :

```
<?php
            echo "<form action=\"test.php\" method=\"post\">";
            $rez = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM shops");
            while($red = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){
                $niz = array(
                       array($red["id"],$red["naam"])
                );
                echo "<div class=\"col-xs-12  col-sm-12\">
                      <input class=\"hidd\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"txtHidd[". $red["id"] ."][kolicina]\" id=\"txtHidd\" value=\"\"/>
                      <div class=\"col-sm-2 col-xs-4\">
                        <div class=\"form-group\">
                            <input id=\"quan\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"number\" value=\"0\" min=\"0\" max=\"10\" onChange=\"proces();\"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class=\"col-sm-10 col-xs-8\">
                        Informacije
                      </div>


                      </div>
                    <div class=\"footer\" style=\"position: fixed;bottom: 0;width: 100%;left:0;\">
                        <a href=\"home.php\" title=\"Ga terug\" class=\"col-xs-6 col-sm-6 btn btn-info\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></span> Niets toevoegen</a>
                        <button class=\"col-xs-6 col-sm-6 btn btn-danger\" type=\"submit\" name=\"btnNaruci\" id=\"btnNaruci\">
                            Leg in winkelmand <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>";
            }
                 echo "</form>";

        ?>
```

I want to update this hidden field for every result. I have now 5 results but if i increase quantity, the hidden field get value only if i increase quantity of first result.

I have onChange by the quantity input field and then in javascript i get the value of that field and add it to the value of the hidden field, but the value of the hidden field is changed only for the first result in while loop..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need the body of your `proces()` function to say for sure, but I think you reference your input field by id, all 5 input fields have the same id. Only first gets updated and that's the problem. Either give different ids (by adding count) or reference by class. That would work, however having same id for multiple fields is not a good idea.

Post the body of the function and I can give more detailed help.

Ok, so they do have the same id. You could go by class to update them like this:

```
var quan = document.getElementById("quan").value; 
var hiddenfields = document.getElementsByClassName('hidd');
for (var i = 0; i < hiddenfields.length; ++i) {
    var item = hiddenfields[i];  
    item.value = quan;
}
```

Or if it's ok tu use JQuery:

```
var quan = $("#quan").val();
$( ".hidd" ).val(quan);
```

Based on your comment:

I see. I think simplest would be to do the following:
In your php code add id (concat as string), and add it to the call of your updating function
This might not compile, but gives you the idea:

```
$i = 1; 
while($red = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){
                // ...
                echo "<div class=\"col-xs-12  col-sm-12\">
                // ...
                      <input class=\"hidd\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"txtHidd[". $red["id"] ."][kolicina]\" id=\"txtHidd".$i."\" value=\"\"/>
                      <div class=\"col-sm-2 col-xs-4\">
                        <div class=\"form-group\">
                            <input id=\"quan".$i."\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"number\" value=\"0\" min=\"0\" max=\"10\" onChange=\"proces('quan".$i."', 'txtHidd".$i."');\"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                // ...
                    </div>";
                $i++;
```

In javascript the updating function would use the parameter

```
function proces(quanID, hiddenID) {
    var quan = document.getElementById(quanID).value;         
    document.getElementById(hiddenID).value = quan;
}
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

I found that the `/"` at the id fields were in wrong position.
Updated sample code. Basically your html output is supposed to look like this (I didn't include name, as it doesn't matter, now we are only looking at id-s):

```
             ...

            <input class="hidd" type="hidden" name="xxxxx" id="txtHidd1" value=""/>
                  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="quan1" class="form-control" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="10" onChange="proces('quan1', 'txtHidd1');"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>


            ...

             ...

            <input class="hidd" type="hidden" name="xxxxxx" id="txtHidd2" value=""/>
                  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="quan2" class="form-control" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="10" onChange="proces('quan2', 'txtHidd2');"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>


            ...
```

Looking at the id-s and the call of the function. If it's like that, the javascript update part will work perfectly.

Comment: Hi, You're right, the id is the same : var quan = document.getElementById("quan").value;
 document.getElementById("txtHidd").value = quan; but how to add id dynamicaly an d then get it with javascript?

Comment: You can add id in the while loop when you generate them. And in javascript use the class if you won't know how many of the it will be.

Comment: Ok. I did it, but now all the values are the same as the first value. Thus if i choose for the first value 4, and for the second one 2 ..., all values have the value 4..

Comment: Update again. The number `$i` should be inside the string, as part of the id string. I hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand, part of which string? Thanks in advance.

Comment: updated `id=\"txtHidd\"".$i."` to `id=\"txtHidd".$i."\"` so it should resolve to `id="txtHidd1"`, `id="txtHidd2"` ...

Comment: The problem was in onChange=\"proces(\'quan".$i."\', \'txtHidd".$i."\');\" I've changed it in onChange=\"proces('quan".$i."', 'txtHidd".$i."'); \" and it worked. Thanks man million times. :)

Answer (score 0):

That is my test.php page

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include("config.php");
    global $kon;
    ob_start();

    print_r($_POST["txtHidd"]);

    foreach ($_POST["txtHidd"] as $id => $id_prod) {
        foreach ($id_prod as $kolicina) {
            echo "<br />Id : {$id} and quantity : {$kolicina}<br />";
        }
    }


    ob_flush();
?>
```

And result tha i get when i hit a post is next :

```
Array ( [17] => Array ( [kolicina] => ) [18] => Array ( [kolicina] => ) [19] => Array ( [kolicina] => ) [20] => Array ( [kolicina] => ) )
Id : 17 and quantity :

Id : 18 and quantity :

Id : 19 and quantity :

Id : 20 and quantity :
```